# How to calculate difference between dates; limit and sort results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page on which listed are details of a club's football players, their date of births and the dates on which they made their debut for the club, as well as with their ages on debut.

You can see the results displayed [here](http://www.boroguide.co.uk/players/agetest.php).

What I am looking to do, however and without success thus far, is ultimately sort this information by the debut ages and then limit them to, for example, the three youngest debutants.

My main problem is not knowing where to even begin trying this.

The data comes from multiple tables, so the MySQL query has been set up thus:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT dateofbirth, firstname, lastname, id FROM playerengine WHERE dateofbirth!='0000-00-00'") or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($totalRows == 0)
{
        echo "";
}
else
{
        $todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
        {
                $playerId = $row['3'];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td width='20%'>";
                echo "".$row['1']."";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td width='20%'>";
                echo "".$row['2']."";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td width='20%'>";
                echo "".$row['0']."";
                echo "</td>";
                $debutDate = mysql_query("SELECT re.date,re.venue,re.comp,re.opponent,re.score,re.ID,ce.ID,ce.name,re.season, mt.ID as matchId FROM resultengine re INNER JOIN matchteam mt ON mt.ID=re.ID INNER JOIN clubengine ce ON re.opponent=ce.ID WHERE (mt.ID1 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID2 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID3 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID4 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID5 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID6 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID7 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID8 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID9 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID10 = '".$playerId."' or mt.ID11 = '".$playerId."' or (ID12='".$playerId."' AND SI12 != 0) or (ID13='".$playerId."' AND SI13 != 0) or (ID14='".$playerId."' AND SI14 != 0) or (ID15='".$playerId."' AND SI15 != 0) or (ID16='".$playerId."' AND SI16 != 0) or (ID17='".$playerId."' AND SI17 != 0) or (ID18='".$playerId."' AND SI18 != 0) AND (mt.ID!='1624') AND (mt.ID!='1638') AND (mt.ID!='225') AND (mt.ID!='248')) GROUP BY re.season ORDER BY re.season ASC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
                $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($debutDate);
                while ($debutRow = mysql_fetch_array($debutDate))
                {
                    echo "<td width='20%'>";
                    echo "Debut Date: ".$debutRow['0']."<br />vs.".$debutRow['7'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td width='20%'>";
                    $date1 = new DateTime($row['0']);
                    $date2 = new DateTime($debutRow['0']);
                    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
                    $years = $interval->format('%Y');
                    $days = $interval->format('%a') - (int)$years*365;
                    echo "aged ".$years ." years and ". $days." days";
                    echo "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
        }
}
```

I know that mysql_* functions have been depreciated in PHP and will be changing this to mysqli_* before everything's finalised/put live - but any pointers as far as this age thing would be terrific.

Comment: what is your expected output? show some samples..

Comment: You're trying to work out the date differences in php, it'd be easier to do it in mysql, something like select * from players order by debut DESC limit 3, that will give you the result set you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the MySQL [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff). In your case, [datediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) may be the function you need.
e.G. this will get you the age in days they were on debut, ordered by them

```
SELECT dateofbirth, firstname, lastname, id, DATEDIFF(dateofdebut, dateofbirth) AS daysOldOnDebut FROM playerengine WHERE dateofbirth!='0000-00-00' ORDER BY daysOldOnDebut
```

while

```
SELECT dateofbirth, firstname, lastname, id, DATEDIFF(dateofdebut, dateofbirth) AS daysOldOnDebut FROM playerengine WHERE dateofbirth!='0000-00-00' ORDER BY dateofdebut
```

will give you the age in days when they debuted while ordering by the (absolute) day of debut.

you can use the result of a mysql function in PHP by specifying an ALIAS (`select ... AS yourAlias`) and use this alias like it'd be a normal column.

EDIT: of course, you can always add `LIMIT 42` to both of the queries.

Please also consider adding a column which holds the result of the upper expression and is updated with a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). This is important for performance, because the normal queries require the expression to be calculated for *every row*, and everytime you execute the query, but they normally shouldn't change that often.